# Ubuntu apt and dpkg not installed in VM

Tags: ubuntu, apt, dpkg

i have an ubuntu VM and i'm trying to make an installation. 
But i don't have apt and dpkg installed in my VM.
i tried to dowload an apt.deb but i need dpkg to install it.

can some one please tell me how to intall it ? 
Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Open a terminal window and try to run this steps:

```
- sudo -i
- mkdir /tmp/dpkg
- cd /tmp/dpkg
- wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dpkg/dpkg_1.17.5ubuntu5.2_i386.deb or wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dpkg/dpkg_1.17.5ubuntu5.2_amd64.deb
- tar x dpkg*.deb data.tar.gz
- tar xfvz data.tar.gz ./usr/bin/dpkg
- cp ./usr/bin/dpkg /usr/bin/
- apt-get update
- apt-get install --reinstall dpkg
```

Reference: [can't install software--can I fix missing dpkg?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/474646/cant-install-software-can-i-fix-missing-dpkg#answer-474681)

Comment: that does't work, .deb files are *not* tar archives, so tar can't uncompress them.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, unless your `tar` is the one from libarchive (often called `bsdtar`) which supports many archive formats including `ar`. But the syntax would still be `bsdtar xf dpkg*.dev data.tar.gz`. The second `tar` command is also wrong. You could do `bsdtar xOf dpkg*.deb data.tar.gz | bsdtar xf - ./usr/bin/dpkg`

Comment: @StephaneChazelas I actually tried (with GNU tar) before posting this; `tar xf ~/Downloads/gnuradio_3.8.2.0-14_amd64.deb`: fails, starting with `tar: This does not look like a tar archive`

Comment: @MarcusMüller, yes that would be the GNU implementation of `tar` which only support `tar` archives.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas ah, now I understand your first sentence, thanks!

Comment: It's worth noting that on a system where it makes sense to install `dpkg`, i.e., a debianoid, chances are you do *not* have a BSD tar :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller, it's not limited to BSDs. It's the CLI interface to libarchive which happens to be called bsdtar. It's available in the `libarchive-tools` package (formerly `bsdtar`) on Debian-based systems such as ubuntu (though generally not installed by default).

Comment: yes, but how likely is it that you have a minimized debianoid not even containing `dpkg` nor a GNU tar, but a working libarchive-tools installation (not saying that might not happen, but it seems ... very unlikely)